# Difference between Apache reload and force-reload

Tags: apache-2.2, service

I've seen plenty on how `reload` gracefully allows HTTP sessions to finish (as opposed to `restart`). So what's the difference between

```
service apache2 reload
```

and

```
service apache2 force-reload
```

Thanks :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`reload` and `force-reload` are really just an alias for the same commands.

```
        graceful | reload | force-reload)
            if ! $APACHE2CTL configtest > /dev/null 2>&1; then
                $APACHE2CTL configtest || true
                log_end_msg 1
                exit 1
            fi
            log_daemon_msg "Reloading web server config" "apache2"
            if pidof_apache > /dev/null ; then
                if $APACHE2CTL graceful $2 ; then
                    log_end_msg 0
                else
                    log_end_msg 1
                fi
            fi
    ;;
```

Comment: This is not the implementation on my flavor of Linux--best to look inside the httpd init.d script on your system (like larsys' answer suggests) and see what the difference is for you.

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like you're on a Debian or Ubuntu system.  Take a look at the Apache init script in `/etc/init.d/apache2`; this script implements all the actions associated with the `service` command.  Look to see the difference between `reload` and `force-reload`.  If you have problems understanding the script, just ask us here.

Comment: Thanks :) Would appear that `reload`, `force-reload` and `graceful` all do the same thing (synonyms for the same case-statement block).